# Why does CONNECT in SQL Developer not work the way it is expected to work

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Using GUI I connect as OLDUSER to a database.

When I type in the following:

```
CONNECT newuser/newpassword;
SELECT USER from DUAL;
```

I get:

```
Connected.
Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected
```

And following that I get **OLDUSER**.

Why is it so? Why does CONNECT disconnect immediately before reaching the next statement when you execute code as highlighted code in SQL Developer?

**UPDATE**

I noticed two different behaviors in SQL Developer:

- When I highlight the `CONNECT newuser/newpassword; SELECT USER from DUAL;`
  statement and CTRL + ENTER them - I will get the OLDUSER instead of new user.
  This is the behavior I described earlier.
- When I run the entire script using F5 - I will get the NEWUSER.

To answer myself:

- For highlighted and CTRL+ENTER executed code: It seems like a 'feature' of SQL Developer that causes CONNECT to disconnect as before the next statement is reached within highlighted text. I find it a bit counter-intuitive as you can use the same highlight + CTRL+ENTER to execute a transaction consisting of multiple statements. They will execute without breaking session.

Comment: That is the way it's supposed to work? The connect script the message refers to is creating a separate connection/session to run the script as `newuser`, without affecting the actual SQL Developer connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a script, we are running your code, and at the end your transaction is finished.

When you do a CONNECT, we'll do the connect for you. And your script is executed.

When it's over, so is your 'transaction' - so we disconnect, and return your session to where it should be - the connection defined by your connection properties in the Connection Panel.

You see a difference between Ctrl+ENTER and F5 because only F5 invokes our script engine and that is what gives you access to SQL*Plus commands like 'CONNECT'

When you do try to run multiple things via Ctrl+Enter, if we see a SQL*Plus command we'll send that through the script engine, but the other queries get executed on the 'main' connection.

What you're trying:

[image]

So the connect works, then we see sql statements and you are doing ctrl+enter so you want results in a data grid so we switch code paths back to single statement execution, and back to main connection (which is HR for me)

And what happens if you use F5:

[image]

We connect, and run queries, and it all happens in a 'local' connection to 'limited_privs' schema, and when this is done running, the 'local' connection is closed and we're back to 'HR' again

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made an update to the question. What you wrote makes sense; my concern is different than expected behavior when you try to highlight text and execute it using CTRL+ENTER in SQLDeveloper. I will be delighted to upvote if you can explain why SQL Developer treats 'CONNECT' as a single statement and immediately disconnects before reaching the next statement.

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba long answer - see my update. TLDR - use F5 not F9/Ctrl+Enter

Comment: What @thatjeffsmith says is accurate. ctrl-enter is always seen as an F9, ie each statement is treated individually, and any queries run there will get their own results tab and _all_ will be run with the worksheet connection.  
The F5 button is what you want, connect, run sql, check results...

Comment: Does this mean I cannot change the connection without using the mouse?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger to execute a script, you can change the connection temporarily, the UI is tied to a connection...you can tab around if you want, or you can spend a 1/2 second to pick up the mouse...or go use SQLcl and stay out of GUIs

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in SQL Developer 23.1, it works in older 22.2 version for me.